# VSCode on Ubuntu throwing AuthenticationException when running empty MVC .NET Core Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to scaffold an MVC .NET Core application on a machine running Ubuntu 16.04. I have created the app by running `dotnet new mvc` and loaded the generated application files in VSCode. When I try to run the applications, it compiles successfully, but fails at runtime.

Chrome is opened and attempts to load https://localhost:5001, but fails. Pointing the browser at http://localhost:5000 redirects back to https://localhost:5001.

The runtime exception is:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
          Uncaught exception from the OnConnectionAsync method of an IConnectionAdapter.
    System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
       at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)
       at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.StorePal.LoadMachineStores()
       at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.StorePal.FromSystemStore(String storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, OpenFlags openFlags)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store.Open(OpenFlags flags)
       at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509ChainProcessor.FindCandidates(X509Certificate2 leaf, X509Certificate2Collection extraStore, HashSet`1 downloaded, HashSet`1 systemTrusted, TimeSpan& remainingDownloadTime)
       at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.ChainPal.BuildChain(Boolean useMachineContext, ICertificatePal cert, X509Certificate2Collection extraStore, OidCollection applicationPolicy, OidCollection certificatePolicy, X509RevocationMode revocationMode, X509RevocationFlag revocationFlag, DateTime verificationTime, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build(X509Certificate2 certificate, Boolean throwOnException)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build(X509Certificate2 certificate)
       at System.Net.Http.TLSCertificateExtensions.BuildNewChain(X509Certificate2 certificate, Boolean includeClientApplicationPolicy)
       at Interop.OpenSsl.AllocateSslContext(SslProtocols protocols, SafeX509Handle certHandle, SafeEvpPKeyHandle certKeyHandle, EncryptionPolicy policy, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
       at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteSslContext..ctor(SafeFreeSslCredentials credential, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
       at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteContext& context, SecurityBuffer inputBuffer, SecurityBuffer outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
       at System.Net.Security.SslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsServer(SslServerAuthenticationOptions sslServerAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
       at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsServerAsync>b__51_0(SslServerAuthenticationOptions arg1, CancellationToken arg2, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state)
       at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(SslServerAuthenticationOptions sslServerAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionAdapter.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionAdapterContext context)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ApplyConnectionAdaptersAsync()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Error: Uncaught exception from the OnConnectionAsync method of an IConnectionAdapter.
```

The automatically generated `launch.json` file contains:

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/MvcMovie.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ,]
}
```

Comment: Looks like you could be missing an SSL cert, or the path to it is unreachable.

Comment: @Jimenemex How would I go about debugging this if it were the case?

Comment: Try looking at your `.conf` file. I think you can disable SSL entirely if you want. Sadly, I'm not that familiar with it.